# Download generated excel file with phpExcel as attachment when form is submitted in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, phpexcel

This is my code. Form submits, but no file is downloaded as attachment. No errors

```
function dn_preorder_form_submit($form,&$form_state){   
            $excel = new PHPExcel();
            $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1',"TEST");

            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="var.xlsx"');
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
            header("Cache-Control: nmax-age=0");

            $file = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel,'Excel2007');

            $file->save('php://output');
}
```

I have tried this solution
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/103690/download-file-on-form-submission
But i still get same results. 
I have tried this code outside drupal and it works

Answer (score 0):

OK, i solved it by inserting exit() at the end of the code

```
function dn_preorder_form_submit($form,&$form_state){   
            $excel = new PHPExcel();
            $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1',"TEST");

            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="var.xlsx"');
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
            header("Cache-Control: nmax-age=0");

            $file = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel,'Excel2007');

            $file->save('php://output');
            exit();
}
```